# how to find operator in sting and calculate as per my formula?

Tags: php, operators, calculation

I have formula in string format store in my database. i just want calculate by pass cost value.

```
$cost = 5;
$formula = '{{cost}} * 1.5 + 3';
$formula = str_replace('{{cost}}', $cost, $formula);
```

Comment: Why you need to replace string ?? you can calculate by `$formula = {{cost}}'.'* 1.5 + 3';`

Comment: because this formula store in my database

Comment: An answer would vary depending on the origin of `$cost`. If it's user-supplied input, more effort was required to evaluate the expression. (Though whitelisting by typecasting might suffice here).

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag ,yivi ,Al Foиce I really don't understand that you marked as unclear. As you can see that one developer gave the perfect solutions and happy with that solution. This is really strange that you marked as unclear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` after your lines of code.

```
echo eval('return '.$formula.';');
```

> Please keep in mind that Using `eval` function is very dangerous when you can't control the string argument.